# Skill of graphing and sketching functions.

Tags: calculus, reference-request, soft-question

I am reading Paul Online Maths Notes for Calculus I. I am reading it on my own. Everything was fine untill I reached Application of Integration section. I am not particularly good at graphing and sketching functions. It is causing me problems in understanding the problem and visualizing the situation.

For example in questions on "Finding area between the curve", I am not able to see which function is upper and which one is lower.

Question: Can someone please advise me on how to improve on skill of graphing and sketching functions. Is there an online resource/textbook from where I can read the various techniques? Where should I start learning/building this skill?

I would be thankful if somebody answers this.

Comment: Often times you could do it algebraically. See where the curves intersect by setting the functions equal to each other and then test points in between intersections to see which curve is above the other.

Comment: If you are working on your own, you could always use [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator) to graph the two functions in different colors.

Comment: You may get better answers if you edit the question to link to a specific page where you were confused and describe which graph or problem on that page confused you. The more you can say about exactly what you did understand and not understand, the more chance someone has to figure out how to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calci/AreaBetweenCurves.aspx, there are two graphs with two functions shown on each graph.

The first graph has an "upper" function and a "lower" function. In the figure below I have added labels to show which is which.

[image]

The second graph as a "left" function and an "right" function as labeled in the figure below.

[image]